Differentiate $\int_0^\pi e^{x\cos\theta} d\theta$ wrt $x$ under the integral
By differentiating under the integral sign show that $$f’(x) = \int_0^\pi x\sin^2\theta e^{x\cos\theta} d\theta$$ where $f(x)=\int_0^\pi e^{x\cos\theta}d\theta$
I thought that $\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^\pi g(x,\theta) d\theta = \int_0^\pi \frac{\partial}{\partial x}g(x,\theta)d\theta$ but I’m not really sure where to go from there (or if it applies).

Hint: Leibniz's Integral Rule - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

You are in the right track. Differentiate the integrand with respect to $x$, then integrate the result by parts.

@Gonçalo thank you! I’ve got it now, I didn’t even think to try differentiation by parts on that expression
